# Looking for a good way to organize a web app

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, design-patterns

I am doing a simple Web application which works more or less like this: (simplified)

> **Module Selection page**: When the user
>   selects a module, the module page
>   appears
>
> **Module page**: Contains buttons for
>   various items. Click on a button and a
>   small AJAX script retrieves the item
>   for a Module Handler
>
> **Module Handler**: simple PHP script called from the module page through AJAX. 
>   Does the job by querying the database and checking permissions

My problem is with the issue of the first item: When the user lands on the Module page, the first item should be already displayed, but all the code to retrieve the item is in the Module handler.

I could of course import the Module Handler inside the Module page and query the functions directly in PHP to get my first item, but it feels a bit dirty to include the handler, and then call to it.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: No harm in including the handler..since it seems you need it.

Comment: A good way is to use an existing framework like CakePHP.

Comment: @calum: Thanks. I know it works, and it looks like it's needed, but it feels wrong and I am looking for a way to change it

Comment: Yii is another good framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a good design pattern for a web application, look no further :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

The Model View Controller is a well tested one and various frameworks use it.

In your case, the modules are the controllers, the pages are the views and the handlers are the models.

Comment: Well, as you noticed, I am more or less following the MVC pattern, with the exception that my controller is a jQuery script. My problem is precisely that: I am faced with a decision that apparently requires me to include a model into a view because the view has to be initialized and the controller (client side) is not yet loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Well i can simply suggest let your first view be loaded, be blank. Just do a include to the default module you want to handle. That way, the view will be just playing like a router. Rather then routing it to the request, it will just import it and use it.